# Upload Build On Fabric(Crashlytics) for Test Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I have a query regarding .ipa distribution with Crashlytics.

I only have a .ipa file & I want to distribute to a tester via Fabric. I have no access on Xcode on my machine.

I know that I can distribute If I have Xcode on my system but this time I do not want to distribute from Xcode.

So can anyone guide me how to distribute IPA file using Fabric Beta without Xcode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

You would at least need Xcode's command line tools installed. Then you can run the following command:

```
/path/to/Crashlytics.framework/submit <API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET> \
-ipaPath /path/to/my.ipa -emails TestEmail@fabric.io,AmazingTester@twitter.com \
-notesPath ~/Notes/ReleaseNotes.txt \
-groupAliases GroupAlias,GroupAlias2 \
-notifications YES
```

Comment: Hey Mike, this answer is almost 3 years old now, is this still the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I no longer work on the product, but as far as I know nothing has changed. Perhaps other experts will chime in.

Comment: Yes this is still the only way to upload the build to Crashlytics manually as far as I can see.